# Number of Real roots of cubic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I just have a quick question about a polynomial and its roots,

For example, I was solving the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2+4x+2}{2y-2}$$

I solved it using the basic methods of separation and solved the solution implicitly as $y^2-2y=(x^3+2x^2+2x+D)$,  $D \in \mathbb{R}$

so when I want to solve for $y$ explicitly, I solve the quadratic and get the form,

$$y=1\pm\sqrt{1+(x^3+2x^2+2x+D)}$$

Now, my question is in regard to the cubic $\mathbb{P}=x^3+2x^2+2x+1+D$

My book noted without explanation that , $\mathbb{P}$ is such that for all $D \in \mathbb{R}$, only one real root exists, call it $r(D)$.

My question is, how was this seen so easily? I think there might be something very simple I am missing potentially. I hope someone can help with the explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $\mathbb{P}(x)$ is $3x^2 + 4x + 2$ (doesn't depend on $D$!). By the quadratic formula the discriminant of this derivative is $16-24 = -8$, so the derivative has no real roots. This means that $\mathbb{P}(x)$ has no critical points (ie, no points where the derivative is 0). Thus, $\mathbb{P}(x)$ is either monotonically increasing, or monotonically decreasing. Either way, it will cross the real axis exactly once.

Comment: Great, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Bbb{P}(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1 + D$ and calculate it's derivative:
$$
\Bbb{P}'(x) = 3x^2 + 4x + 2.
$$
Since the discriminant of this quadratic polynomial is
$$
\Delta = (4)^2 - 4(3)(2) = -8 < 0,
$$
it has no real roots.  Why is this a problem?

Suppose that $\Bbb{P}(x)$ had more than one real root.  Pick two of them and call them $a$ and $b$ (with $a < b$, say).  By the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) (really, its special case called Rolle's Theorem), there is a number $c$ such that $a < c < b$ and
$$
\Bbb{P}'(x) = 0.
$$
But, we just saw that $\Bbb{P}'(x)$ is never zero.  Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, so can the method of taking the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial which is the derivative of the polynomial of interest always be used? I mean, always be used to find something out about how many roots of the trinomial exist?